# how to send 2 messages by splitting 1 message which uis more than 4096 characters in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
if (lyrics.length > 4095)
        return message.channel.send('Lyrics are too long to be returned as embed');
      if (lyrics.length < 2048) {
        const lyricsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('GREEN')
          .setDescription(lyrics.trim());
        return sentMessage.edit(`Lyrics for ${songName}`, lyricsEmbed);
      } else {
        // lyrics.length > 2048
        const firstLyricsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('GREEN')
          .setDescription(lyrics.slice(0, 2048));
        const secondLyricsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('')
          .setDescription(lyrics.slice(2048, lyrics.length));
        sentMessage.edit(`Lyrics for ${songName}`, firstLyricsEmbed);
        message.channel.send(secondLyricsEmbed);
        return;
      }
```

how can i send lyrics of a song which is more than 4096 characters im thinking of sending it in two messages or by doing the reaction thing. can anybody help. it is at

if(lyrics.length > 4096) return message.channel.send('bla bla bla)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `send` methods accepts various options, see [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions). One of the options it accepts is `split`:

```
Whether or not the message should be split into multiple messages if it exceeds the character limit. If an object is provided, these are the options for splitting the message
```

There are multiple options for split as well (see the documentation), the easiest would be to set it to true

```js
message.channel.send(lyrics, { split: true })
```

Edit: I just noticed you are trying to split plain text inside a embed, in this case you can use [Util.splitMessage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-splitMessage)

```js
const { Util, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

// Returns an array of strings
const [first, ...rest] = Util.splitMessage(lyrics, { maxLength: 4096 })

// Set base options for embed, initially it has the first 4096 characters of the lyrics
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("BLUE")
  .setDescription(first)

// Max characters were not reached so there is no "rest" in the array
if (!rest.length) {
  // Send just the embed with the first element from the array
  return message.channel.send(embed)
}

// Get the other parts of the array with max char count
for (const text of rest) {
  // Add new description to the base embed
  embed.setDescription(text)

  await message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Comment: wont work it sends 1 message per embed and not 4096 characters per embed and rest in the other embed. it sends foe eg = word -- example
output = e

x

a
m
p
l
e 
per line

Comment: what exactly should i put in rest? const [first, ..rest] that one

Comment: This is called destructuring assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment you don't have to change anything about the code, Util.splitMessage should give you an array of strings with a max length of 4096 assuming lyrics is the full character one